# How to generate random data for heavily skewed sample

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a actual set of data where the variables are heavily skewed, both positively and negatively.

I need to generate random sample data for the values going forward. The data needs to be similarly skewed for the variables, so that the covariance and correlation remain reasonably similar.

I had planned to use numpy.random.multivariate_normal(), as I can easily determine the mean, and covariance values for the data set. However, as the data is skewed, it is not normal.

Using numpy, or sklearn, is there a random number package that can produce similarly skewed data?

The skewness, if anybody is interested is as follows:

```
 rain    2.373325

 temp   -0.286573

 rhum   -0.289834

 sun     1.103147

 vis    -0.303844
```

Comment: I think if you could make a Cumulative distribution function you could do it.  Then you could just RNG a number between 0 and 1, and see where that lands on the CDF.

Comment: scipy has base classes for arbitrary distribution https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous